# ElasticSearch filtered query and filter term

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I'm trying to use a `filter` on a `filtered` query, this is what I'm trying with Sense:

```
GET myindex/catalog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "analyze_wildcard": true,
                    "query": "test",
                    "fields": ["title^3.5", "contributions.authors.name^5", "publisher^2", "formats.productCode^0.5", "description^0.1"],
                    "use_dis_max": true
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "sku": "test-687"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query hasn't any hit, but if I remove the `filter` property I get exactly the item with `sku = test-687`.

I cannot understand why the query with the `filter` doesn't give me the same result.

Mapping:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "catalog": {
        "properties": {
          "sku": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The field `sku` is exaclty `test-687`.

Comment: term is is lower case /upper case sensitive. What is your mapping for the field "sku" ?

Comment: I told you it's exactly that `test-687`, can't be a case problem.

Comment: what the mapping you used ? for example in my elastic index i have a field who is displayed in upper case but in the mapping it is lower case and i need to search the value lowercased on it with term

Comment: The field name is exactly `sku`: `"sku": {"type": "string"}`

Comment: try this : `{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter":   {
                "bool": {
                     
                    "must": {
                        "query": { 
                            "match": { "sku": "test-687" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Great! It seems to work, I added your filter property to my filtered query. Please add it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: glad it help. i think it is a case problem. term is strict with the case, match not. maybe you can edit your mapping and add lowercase conversion to this field, and when you search on it use term with lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the full query is:

```
GET myindex/catalog/_search {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "test",
              "fields": ["title^3.5", "contributions.authors.name^5", "publisher^2", "formats.productCode^0.5", "description^0.1"],
                "use_dis_max": true
        }
      },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "sku": "test-687"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

---

With default mapping the "Standard Analyser is used"  :

> An analyzer of type standard is built using the Standard Tokenizer with the Standard Token Filter, Lower Case Token Filter, and Stop Token Filter.

(More details [her](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) )

Term is case sensitive, match not